# How to delete decrease the nodes in eksctl kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I want to delete the single node of cluster

here is my problem i am create the node where 2 nodes are running only
but for sometime i need more nodes for few minutes only then after using scaling down i want delete the drain node only from cluster.
i do scaling up/down manually
here is the step i follow

1. create cluster with 2 node
2. scale up the cluster and add 2 more.
3. after i want to delete the 2 node with all backup pod only

i tried it with command

```
eksctl scale nodegroup --cluster= cluster-name --name= name --nodes=4 --nodes-min=1  --nodes-max=4
```

but it doesn't help it will delete random node also manager will crash.

Comment: You can use Cluster Autoscaler which can prevent removing nodes randomly. You can read [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node) what CA is and how can it help you achieve for your problem. Let me know if it is helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using a separate node group for the transient load, use taints/tolerations for laod to be scheduled on that node group, drain/delete that particular node group if not needed.

Do you manually scale up/down nodes? If you are using something like cluster auto scaler, there will be variables like `"cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false"` to protect pods from scaling down.

Comment: Yes manually scale up/down nodes.